# Spring: best way to fetch field from Oracle v$database

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an Oracle database and need to periodically access some data from the `v$database` view in my SpringBoot app. `v$database` is a special view that has just one row and contains some internal DB constants and variables. Basically I would like to fetch `CHECKPOINT_CHANGE#` from that one row via a query such as:

```
SELECT CHECKPOINT_CHANGE# FROM v$database;
```

Normally, you would use the Spring Data Repository abstraction along with `@Query` for your usual tables/views and I'm sure that would work here, as well. But considering the fact that `v$database` is a bit "special" and only has one row, it seems a bit over the head.

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about it as far as the user is concerned. It queries like any other table. Under the covers, it is an interface to the control file rather than a data segment, but that is only of interest on the back-end. Just don't try to ask for ROWID. And you will need the "SELECT ANY DICTIONARY" privilege to query it, as with all SYS-owned dictionary views.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. From what you are writing, it seems that quering it via JDBC template would be more suitable than doing it via JPA repository abstraction.